# Problems with one of my hard drives

Tags: hard-drive, badblocks

Using Ubuntu 14.04 for a year in this computer.
Lately I've noticed that listing files in Nautilus were slow.

After a reboot I got I message something like

```
Cannot mount My_Disk, Skip, Manual...
```

I couldn't mount it because of

```
only root has permission to mount
```

Then I edited `/etc/fstab` and changed  from `defaults` to `defaults,user`.

> /etc/fstab
>
> UUID=b6709da9-718e-4af7-bcc9-99b229aff716 /   ext4    defaults    0   1
>   UUID=1324a7c2-37a8-48de-8ab9-ef2988b4ee56 /home   ext4    defaults    0   2
>   UUID=9153edcd-90a2-4689-a145-1a60e951759a none    swap    sw  0       0
>   /dev/sda1 /media/daniel/SAMSUNG_1TB   ext4    defaults,user   0   1
>   /dev/sdb1 /media/daniel/LINUX-2Tb     ext4    defaults,user   0   1
>   /dev/sdd5 /media/daniel/320GB     ext4    defaults,user   0   1

The disk is mounted now but in Nautilus 'Devices' is not listed as a Hard Disk without its name, just 2,0 TB Volume.

This hard drive has two folders, one was accessible and its files listed but the other didn't list anything.

I've tried some tools I've read in some forums but things seem to go worse: it takes a couple of minutes only to show both dirs/folders

Opening the second folder takes a very long time 'loading...' and finally an error message.

```
$ lsblk

 sdb      8:16   0   1,8T  0 disk  
└─sdb1   8:17   0   1,8T  0 part
 /media/user/LINUX-2Tb

$ ls -l /dev/disk/by-id
```

does not list sdb

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/null count=1

1+0 records in 
1+0 records out 
512 bytes (512 B) copied, 0,000118269s, 4,3 MB/s
```

Running this command produces output after a few seconds

```
$ sudo badblocks -b 4096 -c 4096 -s /dev/sdb
Checking for bad blocks (read-only test):   0.00% done, 0:00 elapsed. (0/0/0 errors)
```

After 1.5 hours

```
Checking for bad blocks (read-only test):   0.00% done, 0:00 elapsed.     (0/0/0 err  0.00% done, 1:25:13 elapsed. (0/0/0 errors)
```

smartctl

```
$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb | less
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-47-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org
```

And nothing more for a time

I have installed GSmartControl but after requiring me the password it closes without any warning. Now I started it again while `smartctl` is 'running' and it does not close: `Scanning system, please wait` for a long time.

I don't know what is causing that issue, as I said before I mainly use this computer for mail and web browsers (Opera, Chrome). The disk is used for backup, original images copied from SD disks and from remote server (using rsync)

I realized the problem because of email reports from rsync

> ERROR: stats/dns_cache.db failed verification -- update discarded.
>   rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous
>   errors) (code 23) at main.c(1655) [generator=3.1.0] Created backup_dir
>   /media/daniel/LINUX-2Tb/path-to-dir/
>   *** ERROR: rsync returned code 23

And

> mkdir: cannot create directory
>   â€˜/media/daniel/LINUX-2Tb/path-to-dirâ€™: Permission denied rsync:
>   mkdir "/media/daniel/LINUX-2Tb/path-to-dir2" failed: No such file or
>   directory (2) rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at main.c(674)
>   [Receiver=3.1.0] /usr/local/bin/rsync-incr: line 141:
>   /media/daniel/LINUX-2Tb/path-to-dir3: No such file or directory
>   *** ERROR: rsync returned code 11

Regular reports were like

> Removing old backup:
>   /media/daniel/LINUX-2Tb/.../public_html.past/2016-10-02.23h30-50m
>   Created backup_dir
>   /media/daniel/LINUX-2Tb/.../public_html.past/2016-11-01.23h30/

Is there anything I can do apart from waiting days running smartctl or badblocks?

EDIT 1: I stopped badblock.

> Interrupted at block 20552

I am running TestDisk 6.14 The disk is recognized

> Disk /dev/sdb - 2000 GB / 1863 GiB - TOSHIBA DT01ACA200

Disk /dev/sdb - 2000 GB / 1863 GiB - CHS 243201 255 63

> Current partition structure:
>        Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors
>
> 1 P Linux                    0  32 33 243200 254 63 3907022017
>    [LINUX-2Tb]
>
> No partition is bootable
>
> *=Primary bootable  P=Primary  L=Logical  E=Extended  D=Deleted
>
> > [Quick Search]  [ Backup ]
> >                                 Try to locate partition
>
> **Structure: Ok.**  Use Up/Down Arrow keys to select partition. Use
>   Left/Right Arrow keys to CHANGE partition characteristics:
>   *=Primary bootable  P=Primary  L=Logical  E=Extended  D=Deleted
>
> Keys A: add partition, L: load backup, T: change type, P: list files,
>
> Enter: to continue ext4 blocksize=4096 Large file Sparse superblock, 2000 GB / 1863 GiB

---

> Disk /dev/sdb - 2000 GB / 1863 GiB - CHS 243201 255 63
>
> ```
>  Partition                  Start        End    Size in sectors
> ```
>
> 1 E extended LBA             0  32 32 243201  13 12 3907022849
>   5 L Linux                    0  32 33 243201  13 12 3907022848 [LINUX-2Tb]

Partitions are okay. What can I do?
[image]

EDIT 2:
Now I've used

> fsck -c /dev/sdb1

to fix bad blocks.

I moved the disk to a Mac computer (it is ext4 format but I have FUSE for Mac and fuse-ext2 extension to read ext4 disk format)

I am running rsync to backup files from damaged disk to another Mac formatted HD.  Some files are copied fast and others very very slow (1Kb/sec !).  Despite that all files copied open good from new disk, none seem to be corrupted.

If files are okay, what can cause those occasionally very low data transfer rate?

Comment: Your question/problem description is not very clear. You present a lot of data, but seemingly not relevant to your problem? What happened just before the problem occurred? What do you think started the problem? Please re-read your text using the eyes of a bystander, and see if you can edit to clear it up for us. Use complete sentences, etc. Thanks.

Comment: post a copy of your /etc/fstab file also could be helpful

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll do that.  This is a 2+ years old HD. Nothing changed but recommended updates. "Checking for bad blocks (read-only test):   0.00% done, 0:00 elapsed. (0/0/0 err  0.00% done, 10:56:09 elapsed. (0/0/0 errors)"

Comment: "Checking for bad blocks (read-only test):   0.00% done, 0:00 elapsed. (0/0/0 err  0.00% done, 22:53:34 elapsed. (0/0/0 errors)"  What does it mean?